# AWS S3 as Docker volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, docker-volume, s3fs

I'm trying to set up a Gitlab CI Pipeline using Docker on AWS EC2. Everything worked as expected until I hit the storage cap on my EC2 instance (8GB). As I quickly learn, a pipeline could easily use up 1-2 GB of data. Having 4 on the server and everything stop.

Granted I could look into optimising Docker storage usage e.g. using Alpine, however I do need a more permanent solution because 8GB would hardly suffice.

I have been trying to use `s3` bucket, with [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), as Docker volume to handle my data hunger pipelines but to no avail. **Docker volume use hardlinks which are not supported by `s3fs`**.

Is this possible to configure Docker to use `symlink` instead? Or alternatively, if are there other packages which mount `s3` as a "true" filesystem?

Comment: Have you considered adding another EBS volume of the appropriate size to your instance?

Comment: Is this an option for **reserved** instance? I thought an EC2 instance spec was locked once you've reserved it.

Comment: You should be able to increase the storage limit, Reserved Instance is for EC2 family reservation (Or equivalent of different EC2 family)

Comment: A Reserved Instance is a billing mechanism and not an actual physical machine. Items such as extra storage, data transfer, etc are not included in the reserved instance price.

Comment: Thanks guy! I managed to up the volume of my EC2. Problem solved! However, I'm still interested if the original idea is valid. It'd be great to utilize `s3` for other similar purposes.